# Figuring out absolute path of mysql to execute shell script

Tags: php, mysql, shell

How to figure out the `mysql` location on a server (windows or linux)?

I would like to run

```
mysql -u USER -p PASS DATABASE < filename.sql
```

but I need the absolute path to mysql, how do I find out?

Comment: Most probably, you will have `mysql` as a recognized command in command prompt, so just typing `mysql` would do. Also, you can configure and add the bin directory to Windows path variable using mysqlinstanceconfig.exe utility, so now just `path` will give you the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unix/Linux: `which mysql` returns the path to the `mysql` executable

I don't know about windows.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to do something similar and found this SQL statement:
    SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'basedir'

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'basedir'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['Variable_name']." = ".$row['Value'];
```

It will tell you the base directory of the MySQL server. Append "/bin/" and then your command.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

`which mysql` wont return anything if its not already in the path.

on linux you can use

`updatedb` 
`locate mysql`

or `find / -name "mysql" -print

Windows just use their crappy search tool

Comment: With this advice you *need* to discuss the running length of both `updatedb` and the `find` and you need o explain when and why the `updatedb` might be a good idea. Finally, there is never any need to be derogatory about platforms other than your favorite. Indeed, as I believe the windows does incremental search database update one could argue that is it some sophisticated than `locate`.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $_SERVER["MYSQL_HOME"];
```